# TamperMonkey: add element after content in a <td> without IDs

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

To clarify, I wish to add a left facing arrow to the right side of a link that is inside of a `<td>` (or rather to all the `<td>` in that column). The arrow will later be used for an accordion dropdown menu.

First, what method can I use to insert `<a class="accordion">&#9664;</a>`? (pure JS if possible)
And how can I have it place that on EVERY `<td>` that contains the barcode number but not cells that contain other links like shipIDs?

<del>jsfiddle.net/pshock13/fotr5p93/</del>

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Shipment ID</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Barcode</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header"> More info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=7546895555555">7546895555555</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=987654321">987654321</a></td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=1234567222222">1234567222222</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=123456789">123456789</a></td>
      <td>other stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in the JSFiddle is a stripped down version of what I'm working with. there are no IDs to work with and any classes used are also used on other elements that have links as well.

Comment: Do you any form of identifier on the table itself, id, class or similar? Is you HTML set in stone or can you add other attributes to cells?

Comment: so the table does have about three classes attached to it. However, because there is only one <tbody> on the page ever, I was able to just skip to that `var theTableBodyRows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");`

Comment: That could land you in trouble, should another  `tbody` end up on the page. If the combination of those three classes are unique to the table that is easy enough to use in `querySelectorAll` ..... `querySelectorAll('table.classA.ClassB.ClassC > tbody > tr > ....etc)`

Comment: I'll probably go with this to be safe, but for the application I'm using it for, I don't think there will ever be another table on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab all the approriate cells with the `querySelectorAll` knowing that the barcode is the 2nd column. Knowing that we can use the `nth-child` selector.

```js
//NEW AND IMPORVED
//Get just the cells we wan knowing barcode is the second column
var barCodeCells = document.querySelectorAll("#theTable tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) > div");
var newElement = "<a class='accordion'>&#9664;</a>";

//Iterate our cells
for(var i = 0; i < barCodeCells.length; i++){  
  //Append the new element to the innerHTML
  barCodeCells[i].innerHTML += newElement;
}


//Old Version
//Get the rows from the body only
/*var theTableBodyRows = document.querySelectorAll("#theTable tbody tr");
var newElement = "<a class='accordion'>&#9664;</a>";

//Loops throug the rows
for(var i = 0; i < theTableBodyRows.length; i++){
  //Knowing th barcode is the 2ns cell get that
  var targetCell = theTableBodyRows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child(2)");
  //Append the new element to the innerHTML
  targetCell.innerHTML += newElement;
}*/
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Shipment ID</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Barcode</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header"> More info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=7546895555555">7546895555555</a></td>
      <td><div><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=987654321">987654321</a></div></td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=1234567222222">1234567222222</a></td>
      <td><div><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=123456789">123456789</a></div></td>
      <td>other stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If the arrow is purely decorative, you can skip javascript and just use CSS

```css
#theTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2) a:after {
 content: '\25C0';
 padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Shipment ID</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header">Barcode</th>
      <th class="tablesorter-header"> More info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=7546895555555">7546895555555</a></td>
      <td><div><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=987654321">987654321</a></div></td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=1234567222222">1234567222222</a></td>
      <td><div><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=123456789">123456789</a></div></td>
      <td>other stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works very well! however, the issue (my fault entirely) is that the <a> is also wrapped in a <div>. so,
`<td><div><a href="http://search.com/AAA/results?s=123456789">123456789</a></div></td>`
How do I go about selecting the div inside to add my arrow?



Found it:`theTableBodyRows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child(2) div");` will select the div inside the 2nd cell of each row

Comment: We just need to tweak the selectors. For the javascript version I've added a new div child : `> div` . For the CSS version I've changed the child selector `>` to descendant, which is a space.

Comment: I like that you included the CSS variant. though for my purpose going forward, I need this to be an element I think.